# when click on submit button debug pointing to [httpget] instead of [httppost]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have created one page using MVC3. I have filled all the details and when I click the submit button it's not doing inserting, just postback and all the details gets lost.

This is controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyAccountIndex()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAccountIndex(MyAccount myacc)
{
    MyAccount ma = new MyAccount();
    var objview = ma.GetCustInfo(myacc);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your View code?

Comment: When I submit the values with the form tag values not getting inserting. It just postback and values getting erased.
But when i remove the form tag the values are inserting.  please give me a solution...

Comment: We need to see the code from your view because that code dictates how the form is being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Change your form in View to:

```
<form action="MyAccountIndex" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```